# what is the Best way to customize bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want just use the basic css and the responsive grids of Bootstrap.
I don't want any components and plugins. What is possible customization so that i can decrease the size of bootstrap css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the source from github. Edit less/bootstrap.less (don't import what you do not need) and recompile Bootstrap. See also suggestion (comment) from @sean-ryan to not overwrite bootstrap.less.

To exclude the javascript plugins, don't include them in your html.

You could do the same with http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Note that if you go this way, you are going to have to remember to NOT overwrite the bootstrap.less file when you upgrade. Might be easier to take this basic idea, but instead of eliminating from bootstrap.less, you add what you want to keep to your own custom.less file, and compile that. This way overwrites are impossible.

Answer (score 2):

simply do this :

1. go to [Customize Bootstrap's components](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).
2. you will find what you need, just choose from the lists that's perfect for you.

**if you need only responsive grids** ( in LESS files *only choose* **Grid system** and **Responsive utilities** ).
3. in ( jQuery plugins ) uncheck all.
4. leave all the configuration after the jQuery plugins.
5. click on Compile and download.

hope this will help you.